# Understanding Factorialize solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var count = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        count = count + (count * i);
    }
    return count;
}

factorialize(1);
```

Why does this return 1 when you use 1? Shouldn't it return 2 because count = 1 + (1 * 1)?

Comment: It is not entering the loop as i=1 < 1 is false. With <= what you expect for 1 would happen

Comment: In the `for` loop, `var i = 1;` sets `i` to `1`. `i < num` is the condition for this loop to run. Since `num` is `1`, the loop does not run, and the function simply returns `count`.

Answer (score 0):

For `num = 1`, when we enter the loop, the check `i < num` returned false, so we do not get to the `count = count + (count * i);` and go to `return` with count = 1.